Is there an Alternative to if-then-else-if-then-else for string compares?
If have to decide on action based on a string. this is currently a very ugly
if X="something" then CodeA1 
  else if X="else" then CodeA2 
   else if X="nothing" then CodeA3 
    else ....

Is there any other construct in delphi10 to do this since Case doesnt accept strings...

That's no valid Pascal/Delphi code you have - mind the correct String literal enclosures '.
